# The ability to pass file names to the Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse method is deprecated

Tags: symfony, doctrine, yaml

I'm new to Symfony2 and working on it for now nearly 3 weeks.
Things are going well but I have 4 deprecated warning at each page that require doctrine to interact (mapping is done through yaml file), whatever the entity used.

> The ability to pass file names to the
>   Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml::parse method is deprecated since version
>   2.2 and will be removed in 3.0. Pass the YAML contents of the file instead. (4 times)

I don't know what I did wrong, or if there is a problem somewhere I can fix to get rid of the warns.

Thank you for your help !

Just in case, here is the full stacktrace :

```
Yaml::parse() (called from YamlDriver.php at line 712)
YamlDriver::loadMappingFile() (called from FileDriver.php at line 115)
FileDriver::getElement() (called from YamlDriver.php at line 55)
YamlDriver::loadMetadataForClass() (called from MappingDriverChain.php at line 102)
MappingDriverChain::loadMetadataForClass() (called from ClassMetadataFactory.php at line 116)
ClassMetadataFactory::doLoadMetadata() (called from AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php at line 332)
AbstractClassMetadataFactory::loadMetadata() (called from AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php at line 216)
AbstractClassMetadataFactory::getMetadataFor() (called from EntityManager.php at line 265)
EntityManager::getClassMetadata() (called from DefaultRepositoryFactory.php at line 67)
DefaultRepositoryFactory::createRepository() (called from DefaultRepositoryFactory.php at line 50)
DefaultRepositoryFactory::getRepository() (called from EntityManager.php at line 665)
EntityManager::getRepository() (called from UserManager.php at line 40)
UserManager::__construct() (called from appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 1582)
appDevDebugProjectContainer::getFosUser_UserManagerService() (called from Container.php at line 312)
Container::get() (called from appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 3632)
appDevDebugProjectContainer::getFosUser_UserProvider_UsernameService() (called from Container.php at line 312)
Container::get() (called from appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 3690)
appDevDebugProjectContainer::getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() (called from Container.php at line 312)
Container::get() (called from appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 2299)
appDevDebugProjectContainer::getSecurity_Firewall_Map_Context_MainService() (called from Container.php at line 312)
Container::get() (called from classes.php at line 2964)
FirewallMap::getListeners() (called from classes.php at line 2606)
Firewall::onKernelRequest()
call_user_func() (called from WrappedListener.php at line 61)
WrappedListener::__invoke()
call_user_func() (called from classes.php at line 1853)
EventDispatcher::doDispatch() (called from classes.php at line 1771)
EventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 132)
TraceableEventDispatcher::dispatch() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 120)
HttpKernel::handleRaw() (called from HttpKernel.php at line 62)
HttpKernel::handle() (called from ContainerAwareHttpKernel.php at line 69)
ContainerAwareHttpKernel::handle() (called from Kernel.php at line 185)
Kernel::handle() (called from app_dev.php at line 30)
```

And if needed, the result of `composer.phar show --installed`

```
doctrine/annotations                 v1.2.7  Docblock Annotations Parser
doctrine/cache                       v1.5.4  Caching library offering an object-oriented API for many cache backends
doctrine/collections                 v1.3.0  Collections Abstraction library
doctrine/common                      v2.5.3  Common Library for Doctrine projects
doctrine/dbal                        v2.5.4  Database Abstraction Layer
doctrine/doctrine-bundle             1.6.2   Symfony DoctrineBundle
doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle       1.3.0   Symfony Bundle for Doctrine Cache
doctrine/inflector                   v1.1.0  Common String Manipulations with regard to casing and singular/plural rules.
doctrine/lexer                       v1.0.1  Base library for a lexer that can be used in Top-Down, Recursive Descent Parsers.
doctrine/orm                         v2.4.8  Object-Relational-Mapper for PHP
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle         v1.3.6  Symfony FOSUserBundle
incenteev/composer-parameter-handler v2.1.2  Composer script handling your ignored parameter file
ircmaxell/password-compat            v1.0.4  A compatibility library for the proposed simplified password hashing algorithm: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash
jdorn/sql-formatter                  v1.2.17 a PHP SQL highlighting library
monolog/monolog                      1.17.2  Sends your logs to files, sockets, inboxes, databases and various web services
paragonie/random_compat              v1.2.0  PHP 5.x polyfill for random_bytes() and random_int() from PHP 7
psr/log                              1.0.0   Common interface for logging libraries
sensio/distribution-bundle           v5.0.4  Base bundle for Symfony Distributions
sensio/framework-extra-bundle        v3.0.13 This bundle provides a way to configure your controllers with annotations
sensio/generator-bundle              v3.0.5  This bundle generates code for you
sensiolabs/security-checker          v3.0.2  A security checker for your composer.lock
swiftmailer/swiftmailer              v5.4.1  Swiftmailer, free feature-rich PHP mailer
symfony/monolog-bundle               v2.8.2  Symfony MonologBundle
symfony/phpunit-bridge               v2.8.2  Symfony PHPUnit Bridge
symfony/polyfill-intl-icu            v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill for intl's ICU-related data and classes
symfony/polyfill-mbstring            v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill for the Mbstring extension
symfony/polyfill-php54               v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.4+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php55               v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.5+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php56               v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 5.6+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-php70               v1.1.0  Symfony polyfill backporting some PHP 7.0+ features to lower PHP versions
symfony/polyfill-util                v1.1.0  Symfony utilities for portability of PHP codes
symfony/security-acl                 v2.8.0  Symfony Security Component - ACL (Access Control List)
symfony/swiftmailer-bundle           v2.3.11 Symfony SwiftmailerBundle
symfony/symfony                      v2.8.2  The Symfony PHP framework
twig/twig                            v1.24.0 Twig, the flexible, fast, and secure template language for PHP
```

***EDIT***

As suggested, I upgraded Doctrine to 2.5, after struggling with some dependancy problems.

Now I have only 2 notices, about stuff from security, which I'm currently working on, based on a deprecated tutorial. Commenting faulty line made notices disappear. Hooray !

Comment: Probably need to update to Doctrine 2.5.  What I would do is create a fresh Symfony application for whatever version I am using, check the vendor versions and update composer.json accordingly.

Comment: I tried this, now I have only 2 deprecation notice. after 2 refresh because stuff was wrong with security and session I guess (28 deprecation warning). I'll edit with the new infos.

Comment: Actually it's progress.  2.8 is sort of a transition to 3.0.  Make sure all your bundles match what 2.8 expects then roll up your sleeves and start wading through the notices.  Or go back to 2.7.  The FOSUserBundle is going to be your big problem.  As well as all your form stuff.

Comment: At the moment, no notices except some deprecated stuff I wrote and I easily fixed. Your Doctrine upgrade did the trick, thank you @Cerad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Cerad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1146363/cerad), I upgraded to Doctrine 2.5 by editing composer.json, and running composer update.

This generated new notices, but related to security stuff I've written in a deprecated way, easily fixed.

For anyone going through the same problem, be careful in your composer.json, Doctrine 2.5 requires php 5.4, and some config.platform.php was set to 5.3.9 for me, which blocked the update. Edit this too if you want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

> The ability to pass file names to Yaml::parse() has been removed.
>   Before: Yaml::parse($fileName); 
>   After: Yaml::parse(file_get_contents($fileName));

source:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md#yaml

Probably you are not using explicity Yaml::parse. It is not a problem until you want to upgrade to 3.0. If you would you can except that change is covered by dependencies (possibly doctrine-bridge). If not you should stick to 2.7 LTS version of Symfony.

I just checked that 2.8 is also LTS. I'm not sure what is the difference.

Comment: The problem is that he don't use `Yaml::parse` anywhere. The error is thrown from a vendor that is required by default.

Comment: I edited answer as I realized my mistake. I didn't read carefully.

Comment: I can't throw away 3 weeks of development and downgrade to 2.7. Plus, 2.8 is LTS, why downgrade ?.

Comment: I edited my answer after further check on Symfony site.
If I where you i would upgrade to 3.0.
Actually I'm planning to upgrade my 2.7 application soon.

Comment: I'm not sure I can do that, I'll submit the idea though. I solved the problem by upgrading Doctrine to 2.5.